# Gisgraphy results appear in two languages

Tags: gisgraphy

I hosted Gisgraphy server for geolocalization issues and imported the data for Saudi Arabia. I need it mainly for reverse geocoding issues. When I request some coordinate it returns the result in two languages (English and Arabic).

I need the result to be in the local language (i.e. Arabic) or at least the city name should be into Arabic. How to achieve this?

edit: 
example of a request and an answer :
to request I use the link:

http://localhost:8080/reversegeocoding/search?format=xml&lat=24.698246&lng=46.846404%22;

and the answer :

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example request and response?

Comment: @vagvaf thank you for the editing. I provided my question with an example. any advice or suggestion is welcome :)

Comment: Hi, I am not familiar at all with gisgraphy. I would check the imported data and specifically if they are available in multiple languages or if there is any way to specify the language in the request.

Comment: thank you for answering me anyway.